# условия для каждго выбранного элемента combobox

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

как проверять через условие чему равен combobox, чтобы изменять данные другие? Что в условие вписывать?

```
def lookupCustomer():
   if комбобокс == один:
      text = "12"
   elif комбобокс == два:
      text = "21"

combo = Combobox(window)
combo['values'] = ("один", "два")
combo.current(0)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lookupCustomer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо `combo.get() == 'один'` (один - это то, что вы написали в values комбобокса) либо `combo.current() == 0` в данном варианте 0 - индекс выбранного варинта (0 - первый, 1 - второй и т.д.)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *


def lookupCustomer(text):
    if combo.get() == 'один':
        print("1")
    if combo.get() == 'два':
        print("2")
    # 2 Вариант по индексу:
    if combo.current() == 0:
        print("другой вариант кода: 1")
    if combo.current() == 1:
        print("другой вариант кода: 2")


root = Tk()
combo = Combobox(root)
combo.pack()
combo['values'] = ("один", "два")
combo.current(0)
combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", lookupCustomer)
root.mainloop()
```